# Why can I not access this Enumerator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to access an enumerator that I use in a script called 'Rocket' to determine when a timer will start. However, when I try to access the variable, it says Assets\Scripts\Timer.cs(19,20): error CS0122: 'Rocket.state' is inaccessible due to its protection level. I have tried making the enumerator public, but that doesn't change anything. It won't let me make it static.

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text timer;
    public float startTime;

    void Start()
    {
        startTime = Time.time;
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (Rocket.state == State.alive)
        {
            float t = Time.time - startTime;
            string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString(); 
            string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2"); 
            timer.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Line 14 is where I try to access the enumerator

```
public class Rocket : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rcsThrust = 100f; //Rotation
    public float mainThrust = 100f; //Upwards Thrust
    public float levelLoadDelay = 2f; //Delay between resetting or loading a new level
    [SerializeField] AudioClip mainEngine;
    [SerializeField] AudioClip Success;
    [SerializeField] AudioClip Death; //Sounds
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem mainEngineP;
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem SuccessP;
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem DeathP; //Particles
    enum State { Alive, Dying, Transcending }
    State state = State.Alive; //Whether the rocket is dead or alive
    Rigidbody rigidBody;
    AudioSource audioSource;
    public int LevelNumber;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (state == State.Alive) //Allows you to control the rocket if the state is alive
        {
            RespondToThrustInput();
            RespondToRotateInput();
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) //If the rocket collides with an object, it will either die or win, depending on what the object was
    {
        if (state != State.Alive)
        {
            return;
        }
        switch (collision.gameObject.tag)
        {
            case "Friendly":
                break;
            case "FInish":
                StartSuccessSequence(); 
                break;
            default:
                StartDeathSequence();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void StartDeathSequence() //Playing sounds and particles on death
    {
        state = State.Dying;
        audioSource.Stop();
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(Death);
        DeathP.Play();
        Invoke("RestartLevel", levelLoadDelay);
    }

    private void StartSuccessSequence() //Playing sounds and particles on success
    {
        state = State.Transcending;
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(Success);
        SuccessP.Play();
        TimerController.instance.BeginTimer();
        Invoke("LoadNextScene", levelLoadDelay);
    }

    private void RestartLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(LevelNumber);
    }

    private void LoadNextScene() //Loads success screen
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("victoryscene");
    }

    private void RespondToThrustInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) // can thrust while rotating
        {
            ApplyThrust();
        }
        else
        {
            audioSource.Stop();
            mainEngineP.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void ApplyThrust()
    {
        rigidBody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * mainThrust * Time.deltaTime);
        if (!audioSource.isPlaying) // so it doesn't layer
        {
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(mainEngine);
        }
        mainEngineP.Play();
    }

    private void RespondToRotateInput()
    {
        rigidBody.freezeRotation = true;

        float rotationThisFrame = rcsThrust * Time.deltaTime;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))// D and A are swapped around because the rocket model is rotated 180 degrees
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationThisFrame);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))// 'if' is used instead of 'elseif' because it will still be rotating to the left if 'elseif' is used
        {
            transform.Rotate(-Vector3.forward * rotationThisFrame);
        }

        rigidBody.freezeRotation = false;
    }


}
```

This is the script with the enumerator in it

Comment: You need to make the enum and variable public.

Comment: Which variable? I have already tried making the enumerator public but it does nothing.

Comment: `public State state = State.Alive;`

Comment: It just changed the error I got... instead I get this      Assets\Scripts\Timer.cs(19,13): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Rocket.state'

Comment: Oh wait so i have to make an object reference?

Comment: That is a different problem. Only static variables, meaning variables shared for all instances of a class, can be accessed without an explicit object reference to that class.

Comment: If you can have more than one `Rocket`, you cannot make the `State` variable `static`. Please do some research of what are static variables, they are quite important to understand.

Comment: Also note that by default **all** class members are `private` if you do not explicitly give them a different accessibility!

Answer (score 1):

Rocket.state is an private value that means you cant use it in other class like you code :

```
if (Rocket.state == State.alive)
    {
        float t = Time.time - startTime;
        string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString(); 
        string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2"); 
        timer.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
```

you have to set "Rocket.state" a public value like " public float levelLoadDelay "
so change it to :

```
Public State state = State.Alive;
```

Comment: This answer is partial, it should mention it cannot be accesed like it was an static variable, because it is not.